# wpf and mvvm: link 2 user controls

Tags: wpf, user-controls, mvvm-light

Like described in the title, i'd like to link 2 users control.
one is a list and an other one is detail of list.
I'd like to refresh the detail user control depending on the row selected in my first user control

Are there a way to do this?

Comment: Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682211/wpf-mvvm-communication-between-two-user-controls/24685563#24685563. Instead of executing a command like in my example, you'll just raise a SelectionChanged event in one ViewModel and pass along the new selected item to the other ViewModel.

Comment: You can also use something like the MVVM Light Messenger...http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/696340/Thinking-in-MVVMLight-Messenger. Send the message in one ViewModel and have the other ViewModel registered to receive those messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a `DependencyProperty` on the "List" control which exposes the selected item. Then bind this as the `DataContext` of the second control.

```
public YourType SelectedItem
{
  get { return (YourType)this.GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
  set { this.SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); } 
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
"SelectedItem", typeof(YourType), typeof(YourListControl));
```

WPF something like:

```
<local:YourListControl SelectedItem={Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}/>
<local:DetailControl DataContext={Binding SelectedRow}/>
```

Where `SelectedRow` would be on your viewmodel

Comment: my usercontrols are in contentcontroller in my ViewPage so my binding is in usercontrol or in view? what is youType type?

Comment: The YourType is the type that represents a row in your list. You have a viewmodel which contains a list of YourType and a property SelectedRow of type YourType.

Answer (score -1):

i'm really disapointed with your solutions.
it's difficult for me to understand how it communicates between both usercontrol.
throw the viewmodel containing the usercontrol or the view?

Do you have a minimal sample that i could learn and test for my case?